# Temporale Präpositionen: für und über

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, preposition, time

Wann verwendet man diese Präpositionen, um Zeitangaben auszudrücken? Zum Beispiel:

> Meine Mutter bleibt bei uns **übers** Wochenende.

Kann ich auch "für das Wochenende" sagen? Was ist dann der Unterschied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du kannst beide Präpositionen für Zeitangaben benutzen. Beispiele und kurze Beschreibungen findest Du im Duden.

[Für](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuer_statt_wegen_zuliebe#Bedeutung8a) kann verwendet werden, um eine Zeitdauer oder einen Zeitpunkt (meist einen Termin) auszudrücken.

Mit [über](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueber_auf_darueber_darauf#Bedeutung2a) kann ebenfalls ein Zeitraum angegeben werden, wobei damit verschiedene Bedeutungen verknüpft sind: dass sich etwas über einen Zeitraum erstreckt, dass eine Frist abläuft oder dass etwas während der Dauer einer Handlung passiert.

In den meisten Fällen können die beiden Präpositionen nicht gegeneinander ausgetauscht werden; die Anwendungsfälle, wie sie durch die Beispiele im Duden charakterisiert werden, überlappen sich auch nur wenig. Wenn es um die Angabe einer Dauer geht wie in

> Ich werde ... verreisen.

nimmt man *für*, wenn der Zeitraum in einer Zeiteinheit angegeben wird ("für 3 Wochen") und *über*, wenn er als ganzes benannt werden kann, z.B. "über Pfingsten" oder "übers Wochenende". Mit *über* ist die Angabe dann weniger präzise. Der genannte Zeitraum ist auf jeden Fall enthalten, und es dauert auch nicht viel länger, aber "übers Wochenende" kann z.B. auch schon eine Abreise am Donnerstagabend bedeuten.

Dein Beispiel ist meiner Meinung nach ein Grenzfall. Ich halte *über* hier für weitaus üblicher, aber die Variante mit *für* würde ich auch verstehen, und sie wird laut Google auch verwendet. Die Bedeutung bleibt im wesentlichen gleich, in der Variante mit *für* würde ich eine etwas schärfere Eingrenzung auf das Wochenende heraushören als in der Variante mit *über*. Die Variante mit *für* kann außerdem auch einen Zweck andeuten, der implizit mit dem Zeitraum verknüpft ist:

> Meine Mutter bleibt bei uns fürs Wochenende [Kontext: ... an dem wir die Wohnung neu streichen wollen und jemanden brauchen, der auf die Kinder aufpasst].